# Firebase Database output everything Swift

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

My Firebase database looks like this:

[image]

Now I want to show everything that is `Kategorien` in different labels. I didn't found any tutorial to output more values at once.
This is the code I used:

```
        ref.child("Läden/Kategorien/Essen & Trinken/Fast Food/Mc Donalds/Name").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        print (snapshot)

        self.Inhalt.text = snapshot.value as! String?

    })
```

I want to add a lot of Restaurants and they should all shown in the view.
Does anyone know how to do that or a link to a good tutorial?